# Responsive Web, Appsite Implementation Error

Tags: html, css

html

```
html
</div class="home__data">
                        <h1 class="home__title">I'am mijoung Frontend developer</h1>
                        <h3 class="home__subtitle">hi</h3>
                        <p class="home__description">High level experience in web design and development 
                            knowledge, producing quality work.</p>
                        </div>.home__container{
  gap: 1rem;
}
css
.home__content{
  grid-template-columns: .5fr 3fr;
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.home__social{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content;
  row-gap: 1rem;
```

[That's a good example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmi5E.png)
[That's a bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WOeQ.png)

<h3 class="home__subtitle">hi</h3>

I'm experiencing a problem that only this part is printed in the center of the screen
Which code is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.